# No way to replace string of unknown length with SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Is this even possible?

All I want to do is search for a common string in a Wordpress database column and **delete the string AND everything to the left of the string**.

I was trying variations of the following:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '%(1280 x 853)</p>', '')
```

I've since realized that you can't use REPLACE with wildcards. So is there any other way to do it?

Note: The content to the left of the common string is of varying length, so I wouldn't be able to use any code that needs to specify a certain number of characters.

And yes, I actually want to update every applicable row in the database column, not simply return a SELECT statement.

Any help would be much appreciated. My brain aged 10 years over this problem.

Comment: can you post some sample data with expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM T;
+---------------------------+
| STR                       |
+---------------------------+
| AB(1280 x 853)</p>CD      |
| 1234(1280 x 853)</p>56789 |
| ZYX                       |
+---------------------------+
```

this

```
UPDATE T
SET    STR =  SUBSTRING(STR,INSTR(STR,'(1280 x 853)</p>') + LENGTH('(1280 x 853)</p>'),LENGTH(STR))
WHERE    INSTR(STR,'(1280 x 853)</p>') > 0
;
```

results in

```
SELECT * FROM T;
+-------+
| STR   |
+-------+
| CD    |
| 56789 |
| ZYX   |
+-------+
```

Comment: Wow, you're a genius! This worked like a charm. You just saved me hours of unnecessary work. Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question clearly, you can try this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '(1280 x 853)</p>', -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> ```
> UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = SUBSTR(post_content, 1, (LENGTH(post_content) - 16));
> ```

If any further improved query, I will post in the comment.